# Use placeholders in translation using tags

Tags: symfony, internationalization, twig

In Symfony / Twig, I could use tags by using percentages in my translated block. For example:

```
Hello {{nickname}}
```

would become

```
{% trans %}Hello %nickname%{% endtrans %}
```

This works as expected. The array with placeholders that I pass to Twig, are automatically mapped to %placeHolder%. No extra work involved. So this works with my PHP array from the controller being:

```
Array('nickname' => 'rolandow')
```

When I want to use the nickname inside the translation block, all I have to do is surround it with percentages %. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work when I pass it to `trans`.

Now I would like to translate a whole block of text, using tags. I can't figure out how I can use the tags in my translation. So, my twig would look something like this:

```
{{ say.hello|trans }}
```

And my translation snippet

```xml
<trans-unit id="1">
  <source>say.hello</source>
  <target>Hello %nickName%, how are you doing today? lots-of-text-here</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I got it working by using this in my template, but it feels like doing things twice. I now need to put the array of placeholder into the trans function again. For example:

```
{{ say.hello|trans('%nickName%' : nickName) }}
```

If I want to use other tags that are given to twig in my controller, I need to pass them to the translator as well. Can't I just pass the complete array somehow?

Comment: Are you actually building an array like `$tags = array('%nickname%'=>'luke')` in your controller?  If so you can just do `{{ say.hello|trans(tags) }}`

Comment: Or declare the `tags` variable using the Twig `set` keyword.

Comment: @Luke, no the array is like array('nickname' => 'luke'). That's actually my point, it feels like redundant coding to run through the array and add the percentages. I was hoping there was a better way to do this. I do realise now that doing this in the controller is a much better place than in the template though.

Answer (score 2):

`{{ say.hello|trans('%nickname%': 'rolandow') }}`

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions here so let's cover them.

1) Twig's behaviour is not like a Doctrine query, where each parameter must be bounded. You can pass an array that contains unused parameters to `trans`, so if you don't want to specify `{'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'...}` to the filter, just pass the entire array (example: `| trans(array)`). That's @Luke point.

2) You can translate block of texts using several ways, the most simple is `{% set %}`. The `{% set %}` tag can be used two ways :

- `{% set var = expression %}` or `{% set var1, var2 = expression1, expression2 %}` is the most known and used way: you just put some value inside one or several variables.
- `{% set var %}` block of text `{% endset %}` allow you to set an entire block of text inside that variable. This is useful if you want to put that block into a filter (such as, `escape`, or in your case, `trans`).

So to translate a block of text, you'll do something like:

```
{% set variable %}
block to translate %placeholder%
{% endset %}
{{ variable | trans(array) }}
```

Anyway, I don't see any interest of translating a whole block in one time : we use `| trans` generally after a property (such as `say.hello`), and I can't imagine your xlf/yml translation file with such a design. If you want to use the translator just to fulfill placeholders, just use Twig as it is written for that job :-)

3) About replacing `placeholder` by `%placeholder%` in your parameters array's keys : the point of Twig is: put what you want as placeholder. In such a way, if your translated sentence contains several `%`, you can use `$something$`, `#something#` or even `something` as placeholder.

If your array keys does not contain those `%`, you need to add them, you don't have any choice. If you really want to do it on a Twig file, you can create a macro that will do the job for you, and put it in a file you import in your base layout.

Something like :

```
{% macro trans_pct(property, params) %}
  {% set newParams = [] }
  {% if params %}
    {% for key, value in params %}
      {% set newParams['%' ~ key ~ '%'] = value %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ property | trans(newParams) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

And then use it with `{{ _self.trans_pct('hello.say', array) | trim }}`.

Notes :

- `_self` is the template where is stored the macro (see the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) for more details).
- `trim` is used because I wrote the macro with indentation and line breaks (that's cleaner to read). Those spaces are, by default, printed.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. The interest of translating a whole block could be with a disclaimer, help message, or e-mail footer. Because grammar changes as well, it would require a whole translated block. My point is as you describe at 3: i don't have the % in my array. When using {% trans %} I don't need to add them, so I was hoping I could use Twig the same way when passing with |trans.